# Pyautogui can not interate with "User-Consent" dialog

Tags: python, testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, pyautogui

i encountered a Windows automation problem.

Background: I need to automated the vPro remote desktop E2E flow，the target PC will pops up a "User-Consent" dialog to choose if connect. I try to use pyautogui to interact with this dialog, but it seems click is not work(i can see the mouse move to the destination, and print a message after the click function).
My code is as above:

```
            pyautogui.click(x=int(point[-2]), y=int(point[-1]), duration=0.5, clicks=2)
    
            # pyautogui.moveTo(x=int(point[-2]), y=int(point[-1]),duration=0.3)
            # pyautogui.mouseDown()
            # pyautogui.click()
            # time.sleep(0.5)
            # pyautogui.mouseUp()

            print("done")
```

I also try to press key through pyautogui( because in the real case, i can just press Enter to establish the connection)，it also not work

`keyboard.send_keys('{ENTER}')`

Maybe the dialog is on the different layers so that no matter the click or keyboard press is not work? Or the dialog is different to the common case(how can i identify)?

How can i fix this problem? Appreciate to you watch and reply.

Answer (score 0):

Some applications specifically prevent programs from sending virtual clicks and key presses to them. (For example, anti-virus software that doesn't want a script to automatically disable it.) That is most likely the issue with your dialog.

Also, if by "user-consent dialog" you mean the User Account Control UAC dialog, then those are specifically designed to not allow a script to click on them.